# How to Install Google Play store in my Emulator Using Terminal?

Tags: android, terminal, installation, emulation, google-play

Hi I want install the Google play store in my Android Emulator .I have downloaded the  GoogleLoginService.apk, GoogleServicesFramework.apk and Vending.apk.these files to install, But here i struck because I dont know how to install play store Using Terminal . Can any one give me Basic steps to install Google play store in my Emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- path till platform-tools>adb install location_of_file
- For Linux users : path till platform-tools$./ adb install
  location_of_file

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer , I followed your answer but unfortunately i am getting error like this "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] " why like this ?

Comment: recreate emulator and try it.

Comment: Yes, i have  Re-Installed by using this command line "adb install -r", But now the play store is not visible in Emulator ?